# React.JS Cannot read property within an Array loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code.

```
 var ImageList = React.createClass({
 getComponent: function(index){
      console.log(index);
 },
render: function() {
var results = this.props.data;
return (
  <div className="row">
    {results.map(function(result) {
      return(
              <a className="th medium-3 columns" href="#" onClick=  {this.getComponent.bind(this, 1)}>
                <img alt="Embedded Image" key={result.id} src={"data:" + result.type + ";"  + "base64," + result.image} />
              </a>
      )      
    })}
  </div>
);
}
});
```

The second return function basically loops an array of images and shows them. I wanted an `OnClick` event when clicked should trigger the `getComponent` method. However if the `OnClick` event is within the array loop it throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponent' of undefined.

However if i use the same code and just add the `onClick` even after the looping function like below:

```
 var ImageList = React.createClass({
 getComponent: function(index){
      console.log(index);
 },
render: function() {
var results = this.props.data;
return (
  <div className="row">
    {results.map(function(result) {
      return(
              <img alt="Embedded Image" key={result.id} src={"data:" + result.type + ";"  + "base64," + result.image} />
      )      
    })}
    <a className="th medium-3 columns" href="#" onClick=  {this.getComponent.bind(this, 1)}>
  </div>
);
}
});
```

Ends up working fine. But since i need to keep a unique id for each image only then can i complete the remaining function of `getComponent` the second method isn't much use for me. Hence is there any way to make it work within the Loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope changes within the `.map` method:

```
{results.map(function(result) {
    // `this` is different inside this anonymous function
})}
```

What you want to do is either use ES6' fat arrow syntax, which automatically creates an anonymous function *with the same scope*, or store the current scope of this in a variable:

ES6 Fat Arrow ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```
render: function() {
    var results = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {results.map( (result) => {
            return(
                <a className="th medium-3 columns" href="#" onClick={that.getComponent.bind(that, 1)}>
                    <img alt="Embedded Image" key={result.id} src={"data:" + result.type + ";"  + "base64," + result.image} />
                </a>
            )
        })}
      </div>
    );
    }
});
```

Note that you'll need a transpiler — such as babel.io — to change this into ES2015 which browsers currently understand to run.  This is considered "best practice", as ES6/7 brings better functionality to JS.

Storing a reference to this:

```
render: function() {
    var results = this.props.data,
        that = this;
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {results.map(function(result) {
            return(
                <a className="th medium-3 columns" href="#" onClick={that.getComponent.bind(that, 1)}>
                    <img alt="Embedded Image" key={result.id} src={"data:" + result.type + ";"  + "base64," + result.image} />
                </a>
            )
        })}
      </div>
    );
    }
});
```

Comment: I followed the second method. Would that work on all browsers ?

Comment: Thanks again i was breaking my head for the past 1 hour on this. :D

Comment: @tonyhb in your second example you're not binding, you're just storing the reference to `this` in the `that` variable. There are two other options, you can actually use `bind(this)` for the callback in `map()`, or even easier you can also pass the context as a [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to the `map()` method.

Comment: could you look at this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636720/react-js-this-state-is-undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 arrow functions to automatically preserve this context:

results((result) => {
  ...
})

or just pass `this` as second param to the `map`:

results(function(result) {
  ...
}, this)